# How do I open an Excel file while working with iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

How do I open an Excel file while working with iphone simulator?

Comment: you click start -> all programs -> Microsoft Office -> Excel, if you are on windows. would you give a little more details ?

Comment: @RageZ; the iphone-simulator is a mac-only program, and I'm assuming the question relates to opening the file *inside* the simulator...

Comment: ha sorry forgot the iphone SDK is only on Mac!

Comment: @Stobor: yeah we can assume it is inside the simulator but would have been better if it was stated plus I suppose the simulator would have network access and XCode or there some tools to actually browse the virtual filesystem.

Comment: i working on an iPhone application in which we have to create an application which will xtract data from xls files and add it into address buk of iphone.I m new to iphone simulator...plzzz Helppp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try to use loadData: method of UIWebView with mimetype @"application/excel".

Answer (score 0):

I think Morion is right that you can open an Excel file in a UIWebView, but that [might not work in the Simulator](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11567-open-file-application.html), and I'm not sure how well you could programmatically extract the information you want to add to the ABAddressBook.

Perhaps you want to save the Excel file as a CSV file?  Then you can include it as a resource in your application and parse the contents quite easily?

Or do you want the user to be able to specify an arbitrary Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial available [**here**](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html) which demonstrates how to open **.pdf, .xls** files in your application.

The main class you have to refer for this is `QLPreviewController`. [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This is the Datasource Method you would have to call for that

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{
   // Break the path into it's components (filename and extension)
   NSArray *fileComponents = [[arrayOfDocuments objectAtIndex: index] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

  // Use the filename (index 0) and the extension (index 1) to get path

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:1]];

 return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
}
```

Also someone would like to refer this SO question :**[iPhone - Opening word and excel file without using UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983502/iphone-opening-word-and-excel-file-without-using-uiwebview)**.