# How to open a PDF file in my iPad/iPhone using my iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

How can I open a PDF file that was stored in my iPad/iPhone, using my own application?

Comment: Did you search before asking question??

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983502/iphone-opening-word-and-excel-file-without-using-uiwebview

Comment: "How can I open a PDF file..." is hardly a duplicate of "opening word and excel file" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use UIwebview to load it. It is very simple. If you want more flexibility you should use Quartz framework classes.

EDIT:

To view downloaded PDF, you can provide open-in functionality in your app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981199/adding-open-in-option-to-ios-app) is how you add "open-in" to your app.

Look [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios) for complete tutorial.

Comment: My pdf file is not in my application bundle eventhough can we open it??

Comment: I downloaded the pdf file from iPad.

Comment: You can open it , if it is there in your sand box.

Comment: Ok. You should provide open-in functionality to your app.

Comment: @Vigenesh: How can I make that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial available [**here**](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html) which demonstrates how to open **.pdf, .xls** files in your application.

The main class you have to refer for this is `QLPreviewController`. [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

This is the Datasource Method you would have to call for that

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{
   // Break the path into it's components (filename and extension)
   NSArray *fileComponents = [[arrayOfDocuments objectAtIndex: index] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

  // Use the filename (index 0) and the extension (index 1) to get path

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[fileComponents objectAtIndex:1]];

 return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
}
```

Also someone would like to refer this SO question :**[iPhone - Opening word and excel file without using UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983502/iphone-opening-word-and-excel-file-without-using-uiwebview)**.

Comment: Is this opens the pdf files which are not in my app's bundle but it was in ipad?

Comment: @anonymous, now you are answering even after getting upset from Monish... Dear 'anonymous', this is a community and you should be more polite with your words. Everyone comes here to learn and share their knowledge..

Comment: @samfisher : Yes mate..I totally agree that we have to be polite. But I answered for the sake of this community. This answer is for those people who really care to search for a solution and by chance they click here they do not go without getting an answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Graphics for this task. 
Look at [PDFView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PDFView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000398) sample from apple resources