# how to read pdf file from url in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have pdf file name now i want to open that pdf file from my ipad device with compatable application...

```
NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *parts = [fileurl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

NSString *extn =[filename pathExtension];

NSLog(@"file extn is %@",extn);

NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileurl];

NSLog(@"not existing url is %@",url);
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

now i want to open this file in my ipad device..when i click on it..can any one have idea?...Thanks in advance

Comment: Where your PDF file is ?? In Document directory or on server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIwebview to load it. Check out the answers on this post a while back. [opening pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680645/how-can-i-open-a-pdf-file-in-my-ipad-iphone-using-my-own-application-in-iphone-s)

Answer (score 0):

you can load your pdf on webview

```
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initwithUrl:url];
[self.webview loadRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be help you...

```
// Your code
NSString *fileurl=[FILE_URL_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *parts = [fileurl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

NSString *extn =[filename pathExtension];

NSLog(@"file extn is %@",extn);

NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileurl];

// Take a web view and load the url in the web view
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest url];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [_webView loadRequest:request];  // UIWebView object declared globally

});
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

PDF file can open by UIWebView and WKWebView, you just load the PDF file by a NSURL.